# How can I make the Username also appear at another User?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

When the page loads, you must put in your username. When I send a message in a Window the username shows as it should, but as soon as I send a message in another window, the username stays the same because it's local.

I tried to make a function with the "txt" parameter inside, but that doesn't work.

Part 1:

```
var txt;
    function usereingabe() {
        var user = prompt("Please enter your name:");
        if (user == null || user == "") {
            txt = alert("Ungültige Eingabe");
        } else {
            txt = user;
        }
    }

    $(function () {
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(txt + ": " + msg));
      });
    });
```

Part2:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      io.emit('chat message', txt + ": " + msg);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

function newFunction() {
  function (txt) {
    var user = prompt("Please enter your name:");
    if (user == null || user == "") {
        txt = alert("Ungültige Eingabe");
    }
    else {
        txt = user;
    }
}
}
```

It always shows the Username that you put in at the "prompt".

Comment: It's not clear where you use `usereingabe`,  `newFunction`, and why you're using `prompt` inside server-side code...

Comment: By what I see so far you're expecting to see each one's names in the chat. You should send `txt` AKA `userName` to the socket messaging event. Currently you're not doing this. You're sending only the message value.

Comment: I solved the problem, but thank you guys

Comment: @despamigros if you've solved it then you should post the answer to your question and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem with a split.

```
    var txt;
    function usereingabe() {
        do{
            var user = prompt("Please enter your name:");
        if (user == null || user == "") {
            txt = alert("Ungültige Eingabe");
        } else {
            txt = user;
        }
        }while(user == null || user == "");
    }

    $(function () {
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        socket.emit('chat message', txt + ":==:" + $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
          var username = msg.split(":==:")[0]
          var nachricht = msg.split(":==:")[1]
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(username + ": " + nachricht));
      });
    });
```

Comment: this is not very good practice to send all the data in just 1 string and then spit it you need to send each piece of data in its own variable to improve readability and prevent possible problems in the future

Comment: I just needed that, not more, so after that the application was done. We needed it for a rating in a school project.

Answer (score 1):

There were alot of problems with your code so i rewrote alot of it and improved the readibility

**index.js**

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <div id="messages"></div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="m"></input>
    <input type="submit"></input>
  </form>
</html>
<script>
var socket = io();
var txt;
var user = prompt("Please enter your name:");
  if (user == null || user == "") {
      txt = alert("Ungültige Eingabe");
  } else {
    txt = user;
  }


    function usereingabe() {
    }

    function sendMessage(){
      message = $('#m').val()
      socket.emit('chatMessage', user, message);
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    }

      $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        sendMessage();
      });

      socket.on('chatMessage', function(user, message){
        $('#messages').append('<li><b>'+user+': <b>'+message+'</li>');
      });

    </script>
```

**server.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chatMessage', function(user, msg){
      console.log(user +": " + msg)
      io.emit('chatMessage', user, msg);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

a few pointers

it is not good practice to do `io.emit('chatMessage', user, msg);` you need to just pass the variables and not format the text inside the expression

and you need to name thinks like this `chatMessage` instead of `chat message` to avoid possible problems later on